# Convert String into integer array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I want to convert a string or char array into an integer array. The string is in this format

example:

```
char *temp
1 2
3 4 
9 7
```

that should be converted into

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,9,7}
```

Is there a string funtion that does this for you?

Comment: use `sscanf` to read the numbers from the string one by one, and put the results into an array.

Comment: What is that first code even supposed to mean? Can you please post real code instead of pseudo code?

Answer (score 1):

Was not sure what you are specifically looking for, below is a function you can pass input of form

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
...
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * str_to_int(char *lines) {
    int *int_arr;
    int i, offset, index;
    // alloc mem for int arr
    int_arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * (strlen(lines) / 2));
    index = 0;
    // using sscanf() "convert" string to int
    while(sscanf(lines, "%d%n", &i, &offset) == 1) {
        // offset increments ptr to lines
        lines += offset;
        int_arr[index++] = i;
    }
    return int_arr;
}
```

Comment: There is no way for the caller to determine the number of values stored into the array. Also `"0 0"` will allocate 1 element and cause undefined behavior when storing the second element. Same problem for `"0"`: allocating zero bytes, which may fail and is too short anyway.